# extract substring attributes and values from main string in JAVA

Tags: java

I have the following String:

```
\018attribute1=value1\028attribute2=value2\033attribute3=value3
```

**Note:** the `"\0xx"` is a hard string no special character include and `"\0xx"` is random. I get this string from an api and it contains the "\"  character.

I want to extract attribute names and attribute values

how to do it?

Comment: no, this question is about the special character "\"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` character twice. Once for Java, and once for regex. This turns it into `\\\\`. Then you can use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to build a map of your values:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\0..([^=]+)=([^\\\\]*)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("\\018attribute1=value1\\028attribute2=value2\\033attribute3=value3");
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    attributes.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like so worked for me:

```
String str = "\\018attribute1=value1\\028attribute2=value2\\033attribute3=value3";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("0\\d{2}(.*?)=(.*?)(\\\\|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println("-------");
}
```

It yielded:

```
attribute1
value1
-------
attribute2
value2
-------
attribute3
value3
```

---

The regex assumes that the pattern you need to match will always start with a back slash followed by 2 digits (\0xx). It will then extract the first substring  until it hits the equals sign. Once it matches the equals sign, it will keep matching until it either hits another slash or else the end of the string.

If you will not have the three digits, you can either substitute it with something along the lines of `\0\w{2}` this will match a zero followed by anything which is a letter, number or underscore.